# Regex - Search for valid urls inside archive

Tags: bash, regular-expression, search

I am trying to build a regex so that I look inside a possible URL file in the formats

www.url.X
http://url.x
https://url.x
ftp://url

I was able to search only with http in a string, does anyone have any suggestions ?

Comment: And how would I look inside a file, making regex parse all lines, even with grouped strings?

Comment: Show us a sample of the file, [edit](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/549747/edit) the question, don't post it in the comments.

Comment: try `man grep` to find out about looking in files with regex. and [this](https://regexone.com/) may help with learning regex

Answer (score 0):

```
^(http:\/\/www\.|https:\/\/www\.|http:\/\/|https:\/\/)?[a-z0-9]+([\-\.]{1}[a-z0-9]+)*\.[a-z]{2,5}(:[0-9]{1,5})?(\/.*)?$
```

Comment: Limiting top-level domains to five characters stopped working reliably a long time ago.